# Route [SearchController.php] not defined. (View:

Tags: ajax, laravel

I have the following error: Route [SearchController.index] not defined. (View:

The code i am trying to execute is the following:

Search.blade.php

```
     function fill_datatable(filter_distance = '', filter_hotel = '')
       {
    var dataTable = $('#customer_data').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:{
            url: "{{ route('SearchController.index') }}",
            data:{filter_distance:filter_distance, filter_hotel:filter_hotel}
        },
        columns: [
            {
                data:'distance',
                name:'distance'
```

Now i have the following controller that should relate to this:

SearchController.php.

In my search controller i have the one method:

```
    function index(Request $request)
      {
     if(request()->ajax())
       {
        if(!empty($request->filter_distance))
        {
        $data = DB::table('posts')
      ->select('distance', 'posts_t etc...
```

Web.php

```
       Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
```

Im not sure what is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consult `php artisan route:list`, you'll see that your route's name is `search.index`, not `SearchController.index`.

This should work:

```
url: "{{ route('search.index') }}",
```

or:

```
url: "{{ action('SearchController@index') }}",
```

Better yet, render your routes safe for use in JavaScript in the case of unexpected characters via the `@json` directive, like so:

```
url: @json(route('search.index')),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route name isn't going to be `SearchController.index` - please check documentation [Resource Controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers) for the corresponding route name - in your case to point to `index` action you'd use `search.index`, therefore

```
route('search.index')
```

Comment: No worries - can you mark it as correct answer then to indicate it has been resolved?